# discrete random variables (vectors) and independence

Tags: probability, random-variables, independence

```
X = [7,-5,-4,-2]
Y = [1,-1,2,-2]
```

Are the two random variables independent?

P(X=x) = P(Y=y) = .25 for each value of x and y.

P(X=x|Y=y) is either 0 or .25 for each x and y.

The probability of each ordered pair (i.e. (7,1), (-5,-1), (-4,2),(-2,-2) ) is also .25.

I see no relationship between X and Y; can I say they are independent?

How in general do I approach vectors like this in problems about independent random variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last question is too broad without additional info about the distributions of each random variable.

Given:

1. $\forall x \in \{7,-5,-4,-2\}, \forall y \in \{1,-1,2,-2\}, P(X = x) = P(Y = y) = \dfrac14$
2. $\forall x \in \{7,-5,-4,-2\}, \forall y \in \{1,-1,2,-2\}, P(X = x \mid Y = y) \in \left\{ 0, \dfrac14 \right\}$

To show: independence of $X$ and $Y$
$$\forall x \in \{7,-5,-4,-2\}, \forall y \in \{1,-1,2,-2\}, P(X = x \mid Y = y) = \dfrac14 \stackrel{(1)}{=} P(X = x)$$

Suppose not.
\begin{align}
& \exists x \in \{7,-5,-4,-2\}, \exists y \in \{1,-1,2,-2\}, P(X = x \mid Y = y) \ne \dfrac14 \\
\stackrel{(2)}{\implies}& \exists x \in \{7,-5,-4,-2\}, \exists y \in \{1,-1,2,-2\}, P(X = x \mid Y = y) = 0
\end{align}

However,
\begin{align}
& \sum_{x' \in \{7,-5,-4,-2\}} P(X = x' \mid Y = y) \\
&= \sum_{x' \in \{7,-5,-4,-2\} \setminus \{x\}} P(X = x' \mid Y = y) \tag{*} \label1 \\
&= 1
\end{align}

Note that \eqref{1} is a sum of three nonnegative numbers, so as least one of them is greater or equal to $\dfrac13$.  This contradicts (2).  Hence $X$ and $Y$ are independent.

Comment: This addresses this specific problem, thank you. I got this problem from notes from a course; a similar problem is at http://www.math.harvard.edu/~knill/teaching/math19b_2011/handouts/19b_review_2011.pdf, about slide 7. I haven't seen anyone else talk about random vectors this way, so if there is no general approach, I am ok with that.

Comment: @cumin Next time, it's better to put the link in the question body instead of a comment, so that we know what's your course is assuming: finite probability space $\Omega$, which is not general in [tag:probability-theory] at all. (Any random variables can be regarded as a vector, and expectation is a functional on the space of random variables.)  I see that slide 7/106 is a question about [tag:dice].  You mean slide 14/106? I'm not sure about the notation. It means the same as in your [lecture notes](http://www.math.harvard.edu/~knill/teaching/math19b_2011/handouts/math19b_2011.pdf)?

Comment: @cumin In your lecture notes, a vector in $\Bbb{R^n}$ is considered to be a random variable on $\Omega = \{1,\dots,n\}$.  That's the only way to make sense of that slide.  For a finite $\Omega$, to prove that two random variables $X,Y$ are independent is to check $$\forall x,y, P(X = x \mid Y = y) = P(X = x), \text{ or equivalently} \\ E[1_x1_y] = E[1_x] E[1_y]$$  That's *the* way to show independence.  In other words, you may *classify* the entries of $X$ according to their values.  Then, in each class, see if the distribution of $Y$ has changed.

Comment: @cumin If they are independent, the distribution of $Y$ should be left unchanged.  In the question body, **your vector notation for random variables $X$ and $Y$ are not consistent with the given condition (2)**.